# pairing input same name array in PHP

Tags: php

I have two inputs as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" name="prod[][prod]"><input type="text" name="prod[][qty]">
<input type="text" name="prod[][prod]"><input type="text" name="prod[][qty]">
/* The second input set was generated dynamically via jQuery. */
</form>
```

I want to pair each product with its' quantity with multidimensional array with following codes (thanks to @Styphon):

```
$works = $_POST['prod'];
foreach ($works as $work => $value) {
    echo $value['prod'] ." ". $value['qty'] ."<br>";
}
```

However, the results was weird as follows

```
aa
11
bb
22
```

Appreciated if someone can help on this.

Answer (score 2):

You need a multidimensional array. Something like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="prods[0][prod]">
    <input type="text" name="prods[0][qty]">

    <input type="text" name="prods[1][prod]">
    <input type="text" name="prods[1][qty]">
</form>
```

Then in PHP you can access the multidimensional array using `$_POST['prods']`, you can loop through each one using a `foreach` like this:

```
foreach ( $_POST['prods'] as $i => $arr )
{
    echo "$i is prod {$arr['prod']} and qty {$arr['qty']}<br>";
}
```

Comment: should I use `prods[][prod]`? @Styphon . As fyi, I use [link]http://www.smarttutorials.net/add-remove-table-rows-jquery/[link] for dynamic rows